# Generate already expanded Table of contents using python docxtpl library and MS word

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am working on doc generation using the `python-docxtpl` library. So, I have created a template to use, in which I have a dummy Table of contents. When I generate doc using this template, generated doc has dummy ToC only. But when I click on `update table of contents` option, then it gets updated.

Now my question is, can I get Table of contents already populated without clicking on `update table of contents` option?

This is how, a dummy table of contents looks like:
https://www.google.com/search?q=dummy+table+of+contents+ms+word&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN821IN824&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWhJ2_tp3iAhXGb30KHTYLAj4Q_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=969#imgrc=N4qNFQzkPYCK-M:

I expect the table of contents to be already populated with all the data in the generated doc file.

Comment: No, you can't - unless you can calculate all the information in your code and write it into the field result. Field updates *require* a document to be opened in the Word application interface. Or they can be opened in SharePoints Word Automation Services. The tricky part about a TOC is the page numbers: until Word lays out a document on-screen there's no way of knowing where the text will break on a page...

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister. So there is no workaround to this such as set table to auto-update entries as we are writing in the word doc?